# parsing json file - scan and separate its attributes

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to parse json file to match name of the user

```
var jsObj = eval('('+request.responseText+')');
var name = document.getElementById("name");
for(var i=0;i<jsObj.names.length;i++)
{
    alert(jsObj.names[i].value);
    if(name.value==jsObj.names[i].properties['name'])
    {
        //do additional stuff
    }
}
```

I have a simple JSON file but I get error as `cannot read property name of undefined or null`
I also tried just `jsObj.names[i].name` still the error persists. If I alert `names[0]` etc I get object...

---

EDIT: My JSON file

```
{ 
  "names":[ 
    { 
      "name": "vcjndjvndfjv", 
      "address": "jnvdfjnvdjn", 
      "country":"" 
    },
    { 
      "name": "vcjndjvndfjv", 
      "address": "jnvdfjnvdjn", 
      "country":"" 
    },
    { 
      "name": "vcjndjvndfjv", 
      "address": "jnvdfjnvdjn", 
      "country":"" 
    }
  ] 
}
```

I have changed the actual values of the attribs but it looks like this..

I have also tried `JSON.parse` but I think the error is related to `jsObj.names[i].name`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You should use `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

> var jsObj = JSON.parse(request.responseText)

Comment: P.S. do not use eval - it's not safety

Comment: for(var i=0;i<jsObj.names.length;i++)
{
alert(jsObj.names[i].name);
if(name.value==jsObj.names[i].name)
{
//do additional stuff
}
}

Comment: So if you still have this error after your changes to :jsObj.names[i].name <- so check length of your names array because maybe you have undefined elements in it

Comment: coming out to be as expected